# What baby fish is this? (UK)

Tags: sea, water, fish, england, photography

What fish is this? I found them in England, near Portsmouth, south of Hayling island on the breathtakingly stunning sand flats out to sea :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they could be Sand Eels or Sand Smelt.

Comment: Could also be sand smelt or any number of small species, or a juvenile of a bigger species possibly. Very hard to tell without an actual specimen out of the water.

Comment: thanks :/ hard to answer question then